# Select multiple items for search keyword by pressing Enter in R Shiny input

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming

I am trying to select items in Shiny's select input by using entered search keyword and pressing Enter to select all matching items for keyword.

The `observe` function in the snippet works if I provide an item like `ALL` that is already present in the list but I want it to work for any typed keyword. e.g. `App` and hit Enter to select all matching items.

It will be interesting to see if there are other custom options that can be coded using jquery or something else to capture the typed input and capture filtered items. Or may be some regex instead of the `"ALL"` that I used in the `if` condition.

[image]

````
    ---
    title: "search and select multiple items by pressing Enter"
    output: 
      flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
        orientation: columns
        vertical_layout: fill
    runtime: shiny
    ---

    ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
    library(flexdashboard)
    ```

    Column {.sidebar data-width=300}
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------

    ```{r}
    #####################
    ### Reactive Parameters 

    Parameters <- reactive({
      c("ALL","Apple","App","Application","Approximate","Appointment","Ap_titude","Apricot","B","Ball","Bat","Battery")
    })

    output$params = renderUI({
      selectInput(
        'params',
        'Parameters',
        choices = Parameters(),
        multiple = TRUE,
        selectize = TRUE
      )
    })

    observe({
      if("ALL" %in% input$params){
        param_selection <- setdiff(Parameters(), "ALL")
      } else {
        param_selection <- input$params
      }
      updateSelectInput(session, "params", selected = as.character(unlist(param_selection)))
    })


    uiOutput("params")

    ```

    Column
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------

    ### Summary

    ```{r}

    ```
````

Answer (score 2):

I found help for [selectize.js](http://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/) . It was hyperlinked on [selectize](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/selectize.html) page of Shiny.

[image: Tags from selectize.js]
I ended up using the `create` function to get it to work. Had to use `callback` instead of `return`. The selection based on search string was showing `undefined`, I could not get it to show correct selection. But since I had the `observe` function through which I was going to `updateSelectInput`, I did not worry about that.

Here's a sample code that I put together.

````
    ---
    title: "search and select multiple items by pressing Enter"
    output: 
      flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
        orientation: columns
        vertical_layout: fill
    runtime: shiny
    ---

    ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
    library(flexdashboard)
    library(dplyr)
    ```

    Column {.sidebar data-width=300}
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------

    ```{r echo=FALSE}
    #####################
    ### Reactive Parameters 

    Parameters <- reactive({
      c("ALL","Apple","App","Application","Approximate","Appointment","Ap_titude","Apricot","B","Ball","Bat","Battery")
    })

    output$params = renderUI({
      selectizeInput(
        'params',
        'Parameters',
        selected = NULL,
        choices = Parameters(),
        multiple = TRUE,
        options = list(
        delimiter= ',',
        persist= FALSE,
        create = I("function(input, callback) {
            callback({
                'value': input,
                'text': input
            });
        }")
        )    
      )
    })

    observe({
      dt <- as.character(unlist(Parameters()))
      if(is.null(input$params)){
        return()
      } else{
          if("ALL" %in% input$params){
            param_selection <- setdiff(dt, "ALL")
          } else {
            param_selection <- dt[grep(paste(input$params, collapse = "|"), dt)]
          }
      }
      updateSelectInput(session, "params", selected = as.character(unlist(param_selection)))
    })


    uiOutput("params")

    ```

    Column
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------

    ### Summary

    ```{r}

    ```
````

And this is the output:

Search string- "App", add it

[image]

The moment you click, "Add App", observe function triggers and updates the selection to all the values that match the keyword.

[image]

Hope this helps someone else that faces the same issue like I did.

Comment: Hmm, trying this and I'm getting `undefined` even with callback.

Comment: I thought I mentioned about it, I also see `undefined` but the `observe` function takes care and updates the input so it does not last for a long time. Did you try to run my working code ?

Comment: Hey I figured it out thanks, but now it's not adding all matching options. Will debug though and report back!

Comment: @tcash21 i was trying to run the code but it seems not working very well.Do you have maybe a solution for this problem because i am trying to solve the same problem (large number of userinput)