# is it possile to filter the user input list which is itself used to fiilter the data in R shiny?

Tags: r, excel, filter, shiny

I have an app that reads data (it can be further developed to be able to read excel,csv data) and then based on unique values by every columns(user input) i can filter my data but the problem here is that sometimes the list of values is large .is it possible to be able to just write some letters or numbers (depends on nature of column)in the user input to get only values that match what we write there exactly like in pivot excel.below is my code without this characteristic.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("df",
                  label="Upload files here",
                  choices = list.files("C:/Users/zbensmid/Documents")),
      uiOutput('choose_cyl'),
      uiOutput('choose_vs'),
      uiOutput('choose_am')
     
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("table")
    )
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  mydata<-reactive({
    fread(input$df)
  })
output$choose_cyl<-renderUI({selectInput("cyl", "cyl", unique(mydata()$cyl), multiple = TRUE)})
output$choose_vs<- renderUI({selectInput("vs", "vs", unique(mydata()$vs), multiple = TRUE)})
output$choose_am<- renderUI({selectInput("am", "am", unique(mydata()$am), multiple = TRUE)})

  output$table <- renderTable({
    df<-mydata()
    cyl_sel <- if (is.null(input$cyl)) unique(mydata()$cyl) else as.numeric(input$cyl)
    vs_sel <- if (is.null(input$vs)) unique(mydata()$vs) else as.numeric(input$vs)
    am_sel <- if (is.null(input$am)) unique(mydata()$am) else as.numeric(input$am)
    filter(df, cyl %in% cyl_sel, vs %in% vs_sel, am %in% am_sel)
  })
  
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Below is the data you can put it as excel file.
[image]

Comment: in `SelectInput`, pass the argument `selectize = TRUE`

Comment: @AdroMine My problem is that the unique values list(userInput) is very large and it contains my names of products (type character containing numbers).Now when i try  select some of them ,i just write some letters existing in thoses names and i get many of them (having match with what i have written).the problem is that i want to select those many names but the problem is that takes a lot of time to select them with the mouse.My question ist it possible to get those names(matches) selected with cetain function in rshiny just like in pivot excel?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49228090/select-multiple-items-for-search-keyword-by-pressing-enter-in-r-shiny-input this should be helpful